# Use css for only one URL

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Can I target a css class for only one URL on my wordpress site?

```
.class a {pointer-events:auto;}
.class a[href="URL"]{pointer-events: none;}
```

This isn't working, is there another way?

Can I do this with javascript?

I need to disable the Add to cart button for a page with a sample part (something that shouldn't be added to cart).

The only other unique attribute is `data-product_id="32570"`

is there a way to target `data-product_id="32570"` in css?

Comment: That should work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGxrNM

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

Perhaps I did not explain well enough. 

I am attempting to disable the add to cart button on this page 

http://partsonline.diamedicalusa.com/results/keyword/Search+For+Parts/search-in/product/search-other/product

However you can only view the price if you are logged in.

Comment: Given the browser support for `pointer-events` and that people may view your site with CSS disabled, you might want to consider a different solution, such as a conditional in your server side code.

Comment: You should target it by that unique attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Are you sure the URL in your `a` element is **exactly** the same as `a[href="URL"]`? You can also change  `href= ` to  `href*= `, so it can match to  `a ` elements which have the `URL` on the `href` but it doesn't have to be exactly. Perhaps you missing some `http://` `www.`. Your code should work.

Comment: @RobBenz and how would you insert JavaScript on a specific WordPress page?

Comment: @Huangism Please answer the question, `.rs_rs_addtocart [data-product_id="32570"] {pointer-events:none;}` worked thanks very much for that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css and target the unique attribute which I think is the best way to target this

```
.class a[data-product_id="32570"] { ... }
```

More documentation and uses here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g68wtwfq/

The CSS as posted `.class a[href="URL"]{pointer-events: none;}` should work.

However, I would suggest that you do it server side (don't output the `href` at all) or with JavaScript (remove the `href` attribute)

If you want to target based on a data attribute

```
.class a[data-product_id="32570"]{pointer-events: none;}
```

should do the trick.

One thing to note as I was doing this is that `a` should be a descendant of `.class`.  If you want to target a link that has `class="class"` then you should use `a.class[attr=value]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select elements by data attribute in CSS.

```
[data-product_id="32570"] {
  /* your styles */
}
```

This is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  It can be prefixed with a parent  `.class` of course.

Your question is a bit ambiguous and I'm unclear if you actually want to target a link to a URL or something *on* a particular URL, but in WordPress, CSS classes are added to the `body` tag of every page to help you identify what sort of page it is and style it accordingly.

e.g.

Homepage only:

```
body.home .foo { ... your CSS properties here ... }
```

Post with ID of 1:

```
body.postid-1 .foo { ... }
```

Page with ID of 2:

```
body.pageid-1 .foo { ... }
```

A category called 'example':

```
body.category-example .foo { ... }
```

Comment: sorry, you're right, It was unclear. 

I wanted to target something ON a particular URL

That's my fault for not explaining correctly, Is that possible?